# Rails active record #or must be structurally compatible query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to query all `products` that have `programs` with `future_end_date_sessions` or all products that have `paths` with `future_end_date_sessions`

Associations are the following :

```
Product :
  belongs_to :learning_item, polymorphic: true
    has_one :self_ref, class_name: to_s, foreign_key: :id
    has_one :program, through: :self_ref, source: :learning_item, source_type: 'Program'
    has_one :path, through: :self_ref, source: :learning_item, source_type: 'Path'

Program has_many sessions
Path has_many sessions
```

I came up with the following query :

```
 Product.joins(program: :future_end_date_sessions).or(
          Product.joins(path: :future_end_date_sessions)
        )
```

However I get the following error `ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]`
How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

So the actual issue is that `Product.joins(program: :future_end_date_sessions)` and `Product.joins(path: :future_end_date_sessions)` have different JOIN criteria and thus cannot be merged together.

The easiest resolution to this in my opinion would be

```
Product.where(id: Product.joins(program: :future_end_date_sessions).select(:id).distinct)
  .or(Product.where(id: Product.joins(path: :future_end_date_sessions).select(:id).distinct))
```

This will result in an OR condition that utilizes 2 sub queries to pull the necessary Product ids from your current join conditions.

Alternatively we could create a join using `Arel` however I have no idea what `:future_end_date_sessions` is or how this works so I am not sure how to accomplish this at the moment.